# Apache mod_rewrite ignoring a RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This one is very strange.

I have two sites for the same client. Certain pages exist in both sites and they don't want to have to maintain two copies, so I've told Apache to redirect these URLs in site A to their counterpart in site B.

I have the following directives in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.site-b.example.com/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ https://www.site-b.example.com/privacy-policy/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^terms/?$ https://www.site-b.example.com/terms-conditions/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^userguide/?$ https://www.site-b.example.com/user-guide/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^abcdefg/?$ https://www.site-b.example.com/user-guide/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

(I'm using mod_rewrite's RewriteRule instead of mod_alias's Redirect / RedirectMatch for a good reason which I won't bore you with here, suffice to say it has to be that way.)

The strange thing is, all of these work except for the `^userguide/?$` one.

- When I go to https://www.site-a.example.com/ I get redirected to https://www.site-b.example.com/
- When I go to https://www.site-a.example.com/privacy I get redirected to https://www.site-b.example.com/privacy-policy
- When I go to https://www.site-a.example.com/terms I get redirected to https://www.site-b.example.com/terms-conditions
- When I go to https://www.site-a.example.com/userguide, no redirect!
- When I go to https://www.site-a.example.com/abcdefg I get redirected to https://www.site-b.example.com/user-guide

What the heck is going on? Is "userguide" some kind of reserved word to mod_rewrite??

Comment: Do you have a page `userguide.php` or a directory `userguide` ? Is it the same for the others ?

Comment: Thanks @Croises - yes it was userguide.html. I must have misunderstood the order of precedence of mod_rewrite directives - elsewhere in the config there's a rule saying existing files & directories are exempt from further rewrites/redirects, but I thought my rules would be processed first. Guess not! If you add your comment as an answer I can give it the tick & upvote it deserves :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that (on top) to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

The other possibility is to delete the `userguide.html` file, if it is not really used anymore.